# Flutter : refresh network image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an quiz app and I noticed that some users suffer from poor internet so that the `Network Image` don't **download** to them. So how to make a button to refresh the image ? and try again to download and show the image in  `Image.network(url)`  If the image does not appear in a certain period of time ?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the [`ImageCache`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package

[flutter_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image)

And instead of using image.network you can use

```
var avatar = Image( 
  image:NetworkImageWithRetry('http://example.com/avatars/123.jpg'),
);
```